# how to get multi properties's mean values using java8 stream?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

there's one Object

```
@Data
class ScoreInfo{
String id;

float cove_score;
float theam_score;
float content_score;
float teach_score;

Date create_date;
ScoreInfoP scoreInfoP;
```

}

and ScoreInfoP is :

```
@Data
class ScoreInfoP{

String stream_sn;

String anchor_id;

String create_by;
}
```

sourceList is a list of ScoreInfo,I want to get cove_score,theam_score,content_score,teach_score's mean values,group by scoreInfoP property and return four mean values for each of these properties.

I can get only one mean value using such code:

```
Map<ScoreInfoP, Double> meanForCoveScore = sourceList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ScoreInfo::getScoreInfoP,
            Collectors.averagingDouble(ScoreInfo::getCove_score)));
```

I want to learn how to get four mean values using java8 or any easier way you suggest achieving this.

Waiting here for your generous help.

Comment: do you mean get each avg value?

Comment: The most elegant way is to create a result class.

Comment: @holi-java  yes,I want to get four avg values

Comment: @Flown can I ask you how to do it in detail..

Comment: but the type for 4 avg values is not `Map<ScoreInfoP, Double>`, it should be `Map<ScoreInfoP, List<Double>>`.

Comment: @holi-java I know it's Map<ScoreInfoP, List<Double>>,I don't know how to write the code to return Map<ScoreInfoP, List<Double>>..

Comment: @holi-java you are correct and it's not that complicated to build such a thing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't anything build-in for this, but it's not that complicated to build a custom Collector for that...

```
 Map<String, List<Float>> result = Arrays.asList(first, second)
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    x -> x.getScoreInfoP().getAnchorId(), 
                    Collector.of(
                            () -> new float[5],
                            (a, x) -> {
                                a[0] += x.getCoveScore();
                                a[1] += x.getTheamScore();
                                a[2] += x.getTeachScore();
                                a[3] += x.getContentScore();
                                a[4]++;
                            },

                            (left, right) -> {
                                for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                                    left[i] += right[i];
                                }

                                return left;
                            }, x -> Arrays.asList(x[0] / x[4], x[1] / x[4], x[2] / x[4], x[3] / x[4]))

    ));

    System.out.println(result);
```

I actually groupBy here on `ScoreInfoP#anchorId`; but you can do it on `ScoreInfoP` - for that you need to change `x -> x.getScoreInfoP().getAnchorId()` to `x -> x.getScoreInfoP()`. But obviously `ScoreInfoP` needs to override `hashCode` and `equals`.

Comment: I use Lombok,with the Data annotation,I don't need to provide hashcode and equals .   I change my code with your template ,it fails.But I think your clear way is right,I need to learn it and find out why it fails.

Comment: It compiles successful now. Now I don't have data to test,I have to  wait a few days to test the code.

Comment: @RickGeng It's actually easy to test that it works... but hey your choice really

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment you should use a proper result class.

```
class ScoreInfoAverage {
  private float cove_score;
  private float theam_score;
  private float content_score;
  private float teach_score;

  // ctor, getter, setter
}
```

---

Then you can use a custom `Collector`:

```
public static Collector<ScoreInfo, ?, ScoreInfoAverage> scoreInfoToAverage() {
  class ScoreInfoAccumulator {
    private DoubleSummaryStatistics cove_score = new DoubleSummaryStatistics();
    private DoubleSummaryStatistics theam_score = new DoubleSummaryStatistics();
    private DoubleSummaryStatistics content_score = new DoubleSummaryStatistics();
    private DoubleSummaryStatistics teach_score = new DoubleSummaryStatistics();

    public void add(ScoreInfo si) {
      cove_score.accept(si.cove_score);
      theam_score.accept(si.theam_score);
      content_score.accept(si.content_score);
      teach_score.accept(si.teach_score);
    }

    public ScoreInfoAccumulator combine(ScoreInfoAccumulator sia) {
      cove_score.combine(sia.cove_score);
      theam_score.combine(sia.theam_score);
      content_score.combine(sia.content_score);
      teach_score.combine(sia.teach_score);
      return this;
    }

    public ScoreInfoAverage average() {
      return new ScoreInfoAverage((float) cove_score.getAverage(), 
        (float) theam_score.getAverage(), (float) content_score.getAverage(), 
        (float) teach_score.getAverage());
    }
  }
  return Collector.of(ScoreInfoAccumulator::new, ScoreInfoAccumulator::add, 
        ScoreInfoAccumulator::combine, ScoreInfoAccumulator::average);
}
```

---

Last but not least you add your `Collector` to the downstream:

```
Map<ScoreInfoP, ScoreInfoAverage> collect = scoreInfos.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ScoreInfo::getScoreInfoP, scoreInfoToAverage()));
```

Comment: I find that a bit too much... you could simply add them and divide later; almost the same as the plain `Collectors.average...` does

Comment: @Eugene Why reinventing the wheel over and over again?

Comment: I don't get your comment to be honest

Comment: @Eugene You've meant the `DoubleSummaryStatistics`, right? So why should I add and divide later, when there's already tested functionality in JDK?

Comment: oh, right - it's just too much for my taste probably and I find it less readable - but it might be me here. Also, you do have a point here (not sure you know about it) - that your solution uses Kahan summation that does the rounding better than simple addition/division.

Comment: @Flown Thank you very much , you provide me with a very detail solution.It  works.